# Select last 25 records from SQL table ASC and order by DESC

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I want to select last 25 records from table (ASC) but i want to display them in excel table DESC (so the last one of these 25 will be first in table). I have created SQL Query but VBA macro said that the query has a incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'

Any advice how to continue? I use SQL server and Excel VBA Macro

```
SQLStr = "(SELECT TOP 25 lot, na FROM ImportantProcessParameters WHERE product = 'Pt Nitrate' AND lot IS NOT NULL AND na IS NOT NULL ORDER BY lot ASC) ORDER BY lot DESC;"
```

Comment: `ORDER BY DESC` you need to specify a field to order by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SQLStr = "select i.lot, i.na 
           from
            (SELECT TOP 25 lot, na 
             FROM ImportantProcessParameters 
             WHERE product = 'Pt Nitrate' AND lot IS NOT NULL AND na IS NOT NULL 
             ORDER BY lot ASC) as i
          ORDER BY i.lot DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select last 25 records from table (ASC)

```
SELECT TOP 25 lot, na FROM ImportantProcessParameters WHERE product = 'Pt Nitrate' AND lot IS NOT NULL AND na IS NOT NULL ORDER BY lot;
```

> but i want to display them in excel table DESC (so the last one of
>   these 25 will be first in table

You should wrap the result to sub table like below

```
SQLStr = "SELECT * 
          FROM (SELECT TOP 25 lot, na 
                    FROM ImportantProcessParameters 
                    WHERE product = 'Pt Nitrate' AND lot IS NOT NULL AND na IS NOT NULL ORDER BY lot)
         ORDER BY lot DESC"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Martin M

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Query

```
select X.lot, X.na 
           from
            (SELECT TOP 25 lot, na 
             FROM ImportantProcessParameters 
             WHERE product = 'Pt Nitrate' AND lot IS NOT NULL AND na IS NOT NULL 
             ORDER BY lot ASC) as X
          ORDER BY X.lot DESC;
```